# Are there tricks to solve seating arrangement problems?

Tags: recreational-mathematics

How are seating problems solved in general? I am stuck on this one for example.

There are 8 houses in a line and in each house only one boy lives with the conditions as given below:

- Jack is not the neighbour Siman.
- Harry is just next to the left of Larry.
- There is at least one to the left of Larry.
- Paul lives in one of the two houses in the middle.
- Mike lives in between Paul and Larry.

If at least one lives to the right of Robert 
and Harry is not between Taud and Larry, 
then which one of the following statement is not correct ?

A.  Robert is not at the left end.

B.  Robert is in between Simon and Taud.

C.  Taud is in between Paul and Jack.

D.  There are three persons to the right of Paul.

Comment: Pencil and paper?  Assignment problems (matching the boys with houses in this case) typically require trial and error (though of course you could use a computer to help, if your patience with computers is greater than with pencil and paper).

Comment: But these are generally asked in aptitude exams where we have to solve 40 questions in 40 minutes, they have around 5 of these types. So you are suggesting there is no 'algorithm' to solve these types?

Comment: Here the exercise is also a multiple choice problem. Likely you can expedite a solution by using the implied condition that no more than one of A,B,C,D can be false.